# C checking for overflow during subtraction

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, integer-overflow

I've been trying to determine whether there is overflow when subtracting two numbers of 32 bits. The rules I was given are:

```
Can only use: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 *   Max uses: 20
Example: subCheck(0x80000000,0x80000000) = 1,
 *       subCheck(0x80000000,0x70000000) = 0
No conditionals, loops, additional functions, or casting
```

So far I have

```
int dif = x - y; // dif is x - y
int sX = x >> 31; // get the sign of x
int sY = y >> 31; // get the sign of y
int sDif = dif >> 31; // get the sign of the difference
return (((!!sX) & (!!sY)) | (!sY)); // if the sign of x and the sign of y 
                                    // are the same, no overflow. If y is 
                                    // 0, no overflow.
```

I realize now I cannot use subtraction in the actual function (-), so my entire function is useless anyways. How can I use a different method than subtraction and determine whether there is overflow using only bitwise operations?

Comment: The first line uses an operator that is not in your list of operators. You can invert and add 1 to get the negative of a number, and then use addition.

Comment: I changed that, thank you!

Comment: I wonder what's the school that gives these utterly brain-dead assignments.

Comment: At least it is an introduction to bitwise operations and two-compliment storage of negative values.

Comment: `a-b` overflow occurs when [`(b < 0) ? (a > INT_MAX + b) : (a < INT_MIN + b)`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93699/29485).  OP's attempt to solve with only bit-wise operators and `!` depend upon UB or implementation defined behavior.

Comment: DIY: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1959565&seqNum=13

Comment: `x - y` is _undefined behavior_ on overflow.  `x >> 31` is _implementation-defined behavior_, even if `int` is 2's complement.  This really is not a good C problem since the goal is to ignore such behavior.

Comment: @chux < and > are not allowed. Only what is listed and = are allowed.

Comment: Can we use `for` and loops? Can we use `==`? Can we use `&&`?

Comment: @KamilCuk No loops, &&, or == either, adding that in.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without relying on undefined behavior. Basically your goal is to represent the check as written by chux, but using only enlisted operators. I have no idea how to implement `<` using only these operators. You could represent comparison `<` by using a loop and `&` and `<<`. Or we can unfold the loop for the number of bits in an integer...

Comment: I looked a lot at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10154975/10420793 to try and figure it out for subtraction, but I didn't have any luck.

Comment: Are your function arguments of type `int` or `unsigned int`?

Comment: @melpomene type int

Comment: Does a return value of `1` mean there was overflow or that there was no overflow?

Comment: **§3.4.3 undefined behavior** *"NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to **behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment** (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message)."* Emphasis added. So the professor who assigned this homework is well within his/her rights to define an implementation that allows this homework to be completed.

Comment: @melpomene 1 means there was no overflow.

Comment: Which is more important: `int` or `int32_t`? `int` may be 16, 32, 64-bit etc.  Fixed width integer like `int32_t` that may be of higher, same, lower rank than `int`?

Comment: Hint: if you're on a machine that uses two's complement, then `a - b` is the same as `a + ((~b) + 1)`

Comment: The only portable solution is the one given by @chux. No bit-twiddling solution can be portable.

Comment: @GovindParmar Even if on a machine that uses two's complement, C does not require [that suggested behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862239/c-checking-for-overflow-during-subtraction?noredirect=1#comment92641157_52862239).  Compiler makers often take advantage (or abuse) UB and IDB in unexpected ways, if not today, maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid undefined behavior, I will assume that integers are represented in two's complement, inferred from your calculation of `sX`, `sY`, and `sDif`. I will also assume that `sizeof(int)` is 4. It would probably be better to use `int32_t` if you are working only with 32-bit integers, since the size of `int` can vary by platform.

Since you are allowed to use addition, you can think of subtraction as addition of the negation of a number. A number stored in two's complement may be negated by flipping all of the bits and adding one. This gives the following modified code:

```
int ny = 1 + ~y; // -y
int dif = x + ny; // dif is x - y
int sX = x >> 31; // get the sign of x
int sNY = ny >> 31; // get the sign of -y
int sDif = dif >> 31; // get the sign of the difference
return ((sX ^ sNY) | (~sDif ^ sX)); // if the sign of x and the sign of y 
                                    // are the same, no overflow. If the
                                    // sign of dif is the same as the signs
                                    // of x and -y, no overflow.
```

Comment: I've already changed that in my function, and it works, so all I need to figure out now is how to make the actual function work.

Comment: P=positive N=negative. P-P cannot overflow. N-N cannot overflow. P-N overflowed if the result of the subtraction is negative. N-P overflowed if the result of the subtraction is positive.

Comment: Your code actually performs the operation that overflows and checks afterwards. This cannot work: Signed integer overflow has undefined behavior in C.

Comment: Of course it applies. Two's complement is an orthogonal concern.

Comment: I mean a C implementation can use two's complement, ones' complement, or sign/magnitude. No matter which it is, signed integer overflow has undefined behavior.

Comment: Disagree about [two's complement overflow is well-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862239/c-checking-for-overflow-during-subtraction?noredirect=1#comment92641775_52863372).  A  platform using 2's complement is not required by C to be well-defined on overflow as this answer hopes for.  See [Simpler method to detect int overflow](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/37177/29485)

Comment: What mis-leads is this answer's "To avoid undefined behavior, ... integers are represented in two's complement, "  That is not a sufficient criteria to prevent UB - encoding can be 2's complement and the function still not as desired.  True this answer may work for you and OP today, yet C does not oblige this code to work as desired tomorrow or on other platforms and compilers.

Comment: Concerning "simply cannot be answered using only the listed operators without undefined behavior." may one can, maybe not?  There are many corners of C that may allow it.  Yet as to this answer, I can identify UB and the over statements about UB and 2's.  It does not make the code _wrong_, just UB dependent and not certainly portable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182049/discussion-between-chux-and-hackerboss).

Answer (score 2):

Please buy and read Hacker's Delight for this stuff. Its a very good book.

```c
int overflow_subtraction(int a, int b, int overflow)
{
    unsigned int sum = (unsigned int)a - (unsigned int)b; // wrapround subtraction
    int ssum = (int)sum;
    // Hackers Delight: section Overflow Detection, subsection Signed Add/Subtract
    // Let sum = a -% b == a - b - carry == wraparound subtraction.
    // Overflow in a-b-carry occurs, iff a and b have opposite signs
    // and the sign of a-b-carry is opposite of a (or equivalently same as b).
    // Faster routine: res = (a ^ b) & (sum ^ a)
    // Slower routine: res = (sum^a) & ~(sum^b)
    // Overflow occured, iff (res < 0)
    if (((a ^ b) & (ssum ^ a)) < 0)
        panic();
    return ssum;
}
```

Comment: Except for the details outlined here https://skanthak.homepage.t-online.de/division.html and discussed here https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26562819

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help! Here is what I came up with to solve my issue:

```
int ny = 1 + ~y; // -y
int dif = x + ny; // dif is x - y
int sX = x >> 31; // get the sign of x
int sY = y >> 31; // get the sign of -y
int sDif = dif >> 31; // get the sign of the difference
return (!(sX ^ sY) | !(sDif ^ sX));
```

Every case I tried it with worked. I changed around what @HackerBoss suggested by getting the sign for y rather than ny and then reversing the two checks in the return statement. That way, if the signs are the same, or if the sign of the result and the sign of x are the same, it returns true.